# Why is this happening on my hover elements?

Tags: html, css

Im adding some hover transitions to my wordpress site, I have combined hvr-icon-forward and hvr-fade classes from [hover.css](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/), On the hover site I combined the classes in the inspector and it worked a charm but for some reason on my site Im getting a white background flashm then shows the correct background color see [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNBHP.jpg)
Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="home_cta">
<a class="hvr-fade hvr-icon-forward" href="#">Building</a>
<a class="hvr-fade hvr-icon-forward" href="#">Plumbing &amp; Heating</a>
<a class="hvr-fade hvr-icon-forward" href="#">Self Build</a>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
#home_cta a {
 background-color: #0619BF;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 50%;
 padding: 16px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold; }
#home_cta .hvr-fade {
 background-color: #0619BF; }
#home_cta .hvr-fade:hover {
 background: #0000f5;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(legacy-direction(to right), #0000f5 0%, #0000c3 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #0000f5 0%, #0000c3 100%); }
```

JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/mrjoshfisher/eh5qu0h7/3/

Comment: You can't transition a gradient.

Comment: What if I want the gradeitn as the main background -color: when I hover over the div rather than a transition. Thought I was doing a background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this flash because there is transition applied on `background-color` and there is css `gradient` applied in css as well.

You need to override in css as follows:

```
.hvr-fade {
    transition-property: color;
}
```

Here is the working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eh5qu0h7/5/).

Comment: that makes no sense. There you are making the transition to the text color that does not change, if you put  `transition-property: width` or `padding`  or any other property its works but is not the solution

Comment: @blonfu In this particular case, transition between solid background color and gradient is not possible so I think its better to remove transition from background...

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Ok, but in that case, isn't better `transition-property: none`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this css for grandient:

```
 #home_cta .hvr-fade:hover {    
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#0000f5+0,0000c3+100 */
    background: #0000f5; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #0000f5 0%, #0000c3 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #0000f5 0%,#0000c3 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #0000f5 0%,#0000c3 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0000f5', endColorstr='#0000c3',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }
```

Updated jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/eh5qu0h7/4/

Answer (score 1):

You may be seeing a momentary flash as the browser replaces the solid background color of the non-hovered state with the rendered gradient. You can work around that by changing your non-hovered background to a gradient (using the intended background color as both the start and end points)…

```css
#home_cta a {
  background-color: #0619BF;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold; }
#home_cta .hvr-fade {  
    background: #0619BF;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(legacy-direction(to right), #0619BF 0%, #0619BF 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #0619BF 0%, #0619BF 100%); 
}
#home_cta .hvr-fade:hover {
    background: #0000f5;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(legacy-direction(to right), #0000f5 0%, #0000c3 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #0000f5 0%, #0000c3 100%); 
}
```

```html
<div id="home_cta">
<a class="hvr-fade hvr-icon-forward" href="#">Building</a>
<a class="hvr-fade hvr-icon-forward" href="#">Plumbing &amp; Heating</a>
<a class="hvr-fade hvr-icon-forward" href="#">Self Build</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you put `background-image` instead only `background` the issue fixed. But there is no transition, the gradient appears suddenly when hover:

```
#home_cta .hvr-fade:hover {
    background: #0000f5;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(legacy-direction(to right), #0000f5 0%, #0000c3 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0000f5 0%, #0000c3 100%); 
 }
```